# Get collection of values from struct's const properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I've got a struct that looks like this:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public const string Property1 = "blah blah blah";
    public const string Property2 = "foo";
    public const string Property3 = "bar";
}
```

I want to programmatically retrieve a collection of MyStruct's const properties' values.
So far I've tried this with no success:

```
var x = from d in typeof(MyStruct).GetProperties()
                    select d.GetConstantValue();
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

**EDIT**: Here is what eventually worked for me:

```
from d in typeof(MyStruct).GetFields()
select d.GetValue(new MyStruct());
```

Thank you Jonathan Henson and JaredPar for all your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are fields not properties and hence you need to use the `GetFields` method

```
    var x = from d in typeof(MyStruct).GetFields()
            select d.GetRawConstantValue();
```

Also I believe you're looking for the method `GetRawConstantValue` instead of `GetConstantValue`

Comment: I know this is an old question/answer but thank you. You are the first person to point out that they are fields not properties.

Comment: When I try to access var x I get an exception: "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." - any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bit different version to get the actual array of strings:

```
string[] myStrings = typeof(MyStruct).GetFields()
                     .Select(a => a.GetRawConstantValue()
                     .ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

GetProperties will return your Properties. Properties have get and/or set methods.

As of yet your structure has no properties. If you want properties try:

```
private const string property1 = "blah blah";

public string Property1
{
    get { return property1; }
}
```

furthermore, you could use GetMembers() to return all of your members, this would return your "properties" in your current code.

Comment: you can also set values with a Property such as:

private string property1;

public string Property1
{
    get { return property1; }
    set { property1 = value; }
}

Also, in C# v 3.5 and later, you can just do get; and set; without actually declaring your encapsulated object.