# Find in struct using c#

Tags: c#, search, struct, find

```
namespace Test
{
    public struct ABC
    {
        public const int x = 1;
        public const int y = 10;
        public const int z = 5;
    }
}

namespace search
{
    int A = 1;
    how to search A in struct and get variable name 'x'
}
```

Comment: While this is likely possible with reflection, there's a pretty good chance that your object model is wrong if you even need to do this.  Can you give a non-contrived example of what you're looking to accomplish?

Comment: Are you not allowed to change that struct? You'd probably be better off using array to loop through.

Anywho, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873892/get-collection-of-values-from-structs-const-properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LINQ` and `Reflection`, you can do the following:

```
var field = typeof (ABC)
        .GetFields()
        .FirstOrDefault(x =>x.FieldType == typeof(int) && (int)x.GetValue(null) == A);

if(field != null) Console.WriteLine(field.Name);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think better option is to turn it to a enum.

```
public enum ABC
{
    x = 1,
    y = 10,
    z = 5
}
```

Then you can use [Enum.GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
string name = Enum.GetName(typeof(ABC), 1);//Will return x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FieldInfo[] myFields = typeof(ABC).GetFields();
        int A = 1;

        foreach (FieldInfo field in myFields)
            if ((int)field.GetRawConstantValue() == A)
                Console.WriteLine(field.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public struct ABC
    {
        public const int x = 1;
        public const int y = 10;
        public const int z = 5;
    }
```

I believe this would fit your needs, **however** I do think you should tell us what you're trying to do (your actual scenario), so we can better assist you.

**Edit**: don't forget to include System.Reflection

Comment: if there is any field of different type that is not convertible to `int`, this code will throw an `InvalidCastException`

Comment: OP didn't mention anything to think otherwise.